# how to select first list Item in <asp:dropdownlist > using javaScript

Tags: asp.net

this is my code

```
<asp:DropDownList id="lue1" runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value=" - Select One - "> - Select One - 
     </asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="Silver"> Silver </asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="DarkGray"> Dark Gray</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="Khaki"> Khaki </asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="DarkKhaki"> Dark Khaki </asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />
<a class="bullet blt-add" id="lnkAddAnother1" href="javascript:" 
   onclick="ShowNextCountrol(this,2)">Add Another</a>
```

function `ShowNextCountrol` will show another `dropdownlist` and `selected listitem` will be first one

Comment: In `href` you should use `javascript:void(0)` rather than `javascript:` other wise it will cause a post back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 document.getElementById("lue1").selectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: myDDL is jquery object and you have used lue1[0] which will be undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
function setSelectedIndex(s, i)
{
    s.options[i-1].selected = true;
    return;
 }
 setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById("lue1"),2);
```

// at the position of 2 give the position u need